# How to design database access from a browsergame

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, postgresql, pdo

First a little bit context:
I'm writing a little browsergame for practise my web-skills and fun :) There are users which own some factories and a main depot. These produce different types of products, which are stored in an internal factorydepot. The user can "gather" the factories to transfer the finished products into their main depot.

For implementation i use PHP with PDO as database-connector. My webserver uses a MySQL-database and my for debugging i use a local Postgres-database.

The user should be able to gather all factories without clicking on the gather-link and wait for response. Therefore I use Ajax so that the user can click all factories once and wait until all requests are finished. To prevent this parallel access from introduce inconsistency into my database, I use transactions with isolation level SERIALIZABLE. Because pdo doesn't support isolation levels, I send at the connection with my Postgres-db a query with

```
SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SET statement_timeout=10000;
```

The second query should prevent parallel transactions from canceling, while another transaction is in progress. Both queries return no errors, but doesn't work. When I send 8 nearly parallel requests, only 2-3 of them returns with success, the other returns an error from postgres "25P02 IN FAILED SQL TRANSACTION". While debugging it seems to me, that the transactions doesn't wait for the other to complete, but I'm not sure with this.

Now my questions:

1. Are there any possibilities to get isolation levels and timeouts working with PDO?
2. Are there any alternatives which i can use? (except heavy-weight frameworks like Zend, i want to explore all mechanics from the deep)
3. Can I solve my problems if i use only one type of database and a specialiced connector like mysqli? I thought it's a good idea to use PDO to be more flexible, but maybe it's not good for browsergames.
4. Is my approach for the database-access ok? Or are there better designs?
5. Are such errors normal and such transactions should be looped until success? When yes, with Ajax at client-side or with PHP at server-side?

Comment: You need a isolated transaction for a `SELECT`?

Comment: @feela : My transaction consists of two selects for fetching the stored amount in the internal depot and the main depot, then I process these with php and write them back into the database. For displaying the factories i use querys without a transaction around.

Comment: This question is over-broad. I'll look at the error message and cause; the rest is close-vote territory for Stack Overflow [as per the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @CraigRinger : After your answer I turned on all logging-features and there is evertime the same error, that the transaction is aborted, because another serializable transcation (Error: "Canceled on identification as a pivot, during conflict out checking."). It seems that my assumption that serializable transaction waits for each other is wrong. They walk like lemmings into death ;) PHP has no threading, so I can't use a worker thread for processing the transactions consecutively. So only my fifth question remains.

Comment: @Gnietschow Yes, serialization errors in serializable transactions are normal.  They do not wait for each other ("block"); all but one of the conflicting transactions aborts if the transactions cannot be serialized. This is explained clearly in the documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html). Your application must be prepared to retry *any* transaction, serializable or not, until it receives confirmation of a successful `COMMIT` from the database.

Comment: Somemore things to learn :) I've solved my problems now with a loop on client-side. I send Ajax requests as long as it returns an error. For my little application it seems to work fine. Scalability is another thing, I look later on.

Answer (score 1):

That error is telling you that you're issuing a statement in a transaction that is already in error. While the earlier statements didn't seem to fail, they might've; PDO and PHP aren't noted for robust and careful error handling.

I strongly recommend that you examine the PostgreSQL log files when running your test. See what fails and where. It may be helpful to set a `log_line_prefix` so you can more easily see which statements come from which sessions by showing the backend process id, something like:

```
log_line_prefix = 'ss=%e pid=%p cmd=%i'
```

You may also want to set `log_statement = all`.

Most likely you'll see that PDO is issuing a query that produces an error, so your next statement tries to execute in an aborted transaction and produces [`25P02   in_failed_sql_transaction`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html).

---

BTW, This doesn't seem like a use case that particularly requires `SERIALIZABLE` isolation to get consistent results. Have you considered just using a `UNION ALL` with your two `SELECT`s?

```
SELECT 'internal', count(inventory_items) FROM internal_inventory
UNION ALL
SELECT 'main', count(inventory_items) FROM main_inventory;
```

or if the schema is nicer:

```
SELECT isinternal, count(inventory_items)
FROM inventory
GROUP BY isinternal;
```